# Connection getting terminated after few seconds in ActionCable, Rails 6

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, chat, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-6

When client comes for subscription, it gets connected, starts receiving pings, channels start transmitting on server and suddenly after few seconds, connection gets terminated with error message "**server restart**". I know the file from which this message comes is https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f675cb30ce813a99b52b139a93e048330922fd9a/actioncable/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb#L41

But I am not getting why is this happening. Moreover this does not happens on my local machine, it is happening on some other sever running development environment

**config/cable.yml**

```
development:  
  adapter: redis  
  url: redis://localhost:6379  

qa:  
  adapter: async  

stage:  
  adapter: async  

test:  
  adapter: test
```

**connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable  
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base  
  end  
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So Here is what worked for me. All related to configuration.

These are the changes, I have made in config/environments/development.rb

config.force_ssl = true
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = true

And most importantly
config.cache_classes = true